# applying custom sharpen layer in the intermediate stage

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have two concatenated models VAE and GAN, and i need to apply sharpening filter to the output of VAE using custom layer, before feeding its output to the GAN, my model is as follow:

[image]

Here is the code of models building:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Layer

i = Input(shape=(1,256,256))
x = vae(i)
x1 = Sharpen(num_outputs=(x.shape))(x)      # MY CUSTOM LAYER
x2 = GAN(x1)
g = Model(i, [x1, x2])
```

and the code for the custom layer (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51683471/how-to-add-custom-image-sharpening-layer-in-keras)) is as follow:

```
class Sharpen(Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_outputs):
        super(Sharpen, self).__init__()
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = np.array([[-2, -2, -2], 
                                [-2, 17, -2], 
                                [-2, -2, -2]])
        self.kernel = tf.expand_dims(self.kernel, 0)
        self.kernel = tf.expand_dims(self.kernel, 0)
        self.kernel = tf.cast(self.kernel, tf.float32)
        
    def call(self, input_shape):
        return Convolution2D(input_shape, self.kernel, subsample=(1, 1), border_mode='same')
```

the error msg i get is this:

```
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_16036\1078305279.py", line 1, in <module>
x1 = Sharpen(num_outputs=(x.shape))(x)

File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\keras122_tf115__GPU\lib\site-        
packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 572, in __call__
self.add_inbound_node(inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)

File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\keras122_tf115__GPU\lib\site- 
packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 635, in add_inbound_node
Node.create_node(self, inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)

File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\keras122_tf115__GPU\lib\site- 
packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 166, in create_node
output_tensors = to_list(outbound_layer.call(input_tensors[0], mask=input_masks[0]))

TypeError: call() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mask'
```

note, i am using Tf 1.15 , keras 1.2.2 and python 3.7

Please, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Ali. Can you please try upgrading to Keras > 2.0.0 and check if the issue still persists. Thanks!

Comment: it is working fine if i upgraded keras to 2.0 but the code i am working on was written in keras 1.2.2 and upgrading keras produces many errors. any idea to change this custom layer to be working on keras 1.2.2, please?

Comment: This is a keras version issue with tensorflow. Tensorflow 1.15 comes with  tf.keras version 2.2.4. What errors are you running into after upgrading keras Version?